# Creating complex queries with WP_Query in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Here's a complex query which we've built using WP_Query. It should:

1. Ignore post id 191

AND

2. Select all posts with 'reihenfolge' <= 18

AND

3. Ignore posts without a featured image

AND

4. Order them randomly

Here is the code:

```
$args_projekte = array(
        'post_type' => 'projekt',
        'posts_per_page' => 18,
        'meta_query' => array('relation' => 'AND',
                                array('post__not_in' => array(191)),
                                array('meta_key' => 'reihenfolge',  
                                      'meta_value_num' => '18',
                                      'meta_compare' => '<='),
                                array('key' => '_thumbnail_id')
                            ),  
        'orderby' => 'rand'
        );
```

However, ALL posts are being shown in a random order. `'reihenfolge <=18'` seems to be being ignored.

What are we missing here?

Comment: you cant use 'post__not_in' inside meta_query array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) is completely wrong. All you parameters inside your arrays is invalid.

- `post__not_in` should be **outside** your `meta_query`
- `meta_key`, `meta_value_num` and `meta_compare` are all invalid paramters **inside** a `meta_query`. This parameters is used **outside** a `meta_query`

You query should look something like this

```
$args_projekte = array(
    'post_type' => 'projekt',
    'posts_per_page' => 18,
    'post__not_in' => array( 191 ),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'reihenfolge',
            'value' => '18',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks Pieter. I added 'type' => 'numeric' to make sure the meta key 'reihenfolge' is treated as a number

Comment: Great addition for consistancy :-). Glad it worked for you. Enjoy :-)